# Is it possible to use GraphQL with Twirp RPC framework by Twitch

Tags: go, graphql, twirp

I have a Golang program working with Twirp and I want to create GraphQl server, but as far as I know, twirp build on top of the Rest API

Comment: graphql is json over http. rpc is a different paradigm. But you can always build an api wrapper over an rpc framework.

Comment: @DakshMiglani should I create a second graphql API to work with twirp API? Is it hard to do ?

Comment: yeah. Make a graphql api and use twirp in the resolvers to fetch the data and all.

Comment: read this article: https://graphql.org/blog/rest-api-graphql-wrapper/

Comment: @DakshMiglani Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## It is definitely possible.

You Just have to make a wrapper over the Twirp based RPC API.

This is a similar case to wrapping a GraphQL API over a Rest API.

You should also [read this article](https://graphql.org/blog/rest-api-graphql-wrapper/), where the wrapping of a graphql api over a rest one is shown.